# NPM Package doesn't have Types

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I'm transforming a small express api to use TypeScript, but some of the packages don't have a `@types/` so when I import them I get a `TS2307` error.

Is there something I can do to resolve the error? Or maybe type it myself, depending on the package complexity. One example is `express-bearer-token`[(found here)](https://github.com/tkellen/js-express-bearer-token)

Comment: You can use either `require("express-bearer-token")` which will basically bypass TypeScript safety for that package, or create the typings yourself and publish them on [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use an node module without typings from Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43529328/how-to-use-an-node-module-without-typings-from-typescript)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The quick way is to create a `globals.d.ts` file and add the line:

```
declare module "express-bearer-token";
```

This will treat `express-bearer-token` as a JS module without typings. More information about that [here](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/project/globals.html).

From there, you can start adding more typings yourself if you wish. You can find some information about writing your own definitions [here](http://blog.wolksoftware.com/contributing-to-definitelytyped#writing-your-own-type-definitions-files_1).

Comment: It worked, I put the file in src directory

Answer (score 2):

### For daisyui

Create global.d.ts in the root directory

Add the below line

```
declare module "daisyui";
```

Note: Stop the server and re-start if you the server is running already.